# async await, using Promise.all not working

Tags: node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am using node v8.0.0. This comes with default async await style of code. I am trying to do some query in parallel and wait for all the promises to resolve then do some operation. But this seems to be not working. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong:

Code snippet:

```
let promises = [];
let allResponse = [];
let allSites = ["site1", "site2", "site3"];
for(let i=0; i < allSites.length; i++){
  promises.push(baseDbHelper.getResponse()); // This returns promise.
}

allResponse = await Promise.all(promises); // 
console.log(allResponse); // this printing empty array.
```

Can anyone please help me if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Does your function the `async` keyword?

Comment: For starters, it should be `allResponse = await Promise.all(promises);` with `promises` with an `s` on the end.  And, the containing function must be `async`.  And, your promises returned by `baseDbHelper.getResponse()` must resolve with a value.

Comment: yes my function starts with async keyword @Hector

Comment: If there are no execution errors showing and `baseDbHelper.getResponse()` properly returns a promise that resolves to a value, then there should be nothing wrong with this code and `allResponse` will not be an empty array.  So, one of those things is apparently not true.

Comment: @jfriend00 it was a typo in my question.. I corrected

Comment: Typos like that in the question tell us that you are not showing us your REAL code and thus we likely cannot see the REAL error in your code.  Trying to reduce your problem to a make believe theoretical question removes most of the places that you make actual errors so we really can't help.

Comment: Implemented properly, the above code works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xjgmgcpz/